Is there an expression that can be used to evaluate the threshold that characterizes a substantial difference between sample means for t-test?
I'm currently performing a paired t-test for the difference between sample means. I have an interest in determining if there is a way to obtain a scalar value for a threshold that quantifies whether the difference between the sample means is substantially greater than zero given a prescribed significance level. Does there exist such an expression or threshold? It would be nice to be able to report that given the results of the hypothesis test, a difference between sample means of "x" or greater was determined to be an indicator of a difference that was substantially greater than zero given a significance level of "y". This result would be used to support the conclusion from the p-value by adding practical significance to the statistical significance of comparing the p-value to the significance level.

I'm not quite sure what you mean. Is it a confidence interval? A standardized effect size (like Cohen's d)? A confidence interval of an effect size? If it's statistically significant, the difference is unlikely to be zero - but whether it's substantial is a different question that probably requires domain knowledge. 1 lb difference in body weight might be statistically significant, but is probably not substantial.  10 lb difference in weight might be substantial, but not statistically significant.

Hey Jeremy, thanks for the recommendations. How would I go about computing a confidence interval of an effect size? I'm working with paired data and would like to use the Cohen's d method to arrive at a result that provides practical significance behind the differences between means. I'm assuming that using a pooled standard deviation would be best in this case, although, it is worth noting that the paired data come from a time-series dataset (comparing means between two points in time).

I've read that 0.2, 0.5, and 0.8 are small, moderate, and large effect indicators, but not sure that this is generalizable to cost data that I'm working with.

The size of effect that is practically or scientifically "substantial" is ALWAYS context-dependent and so any attempt to provide a formulaic threshold will be harmful. Statistical analyses can yield statistical inferences, but only a thoughtful and informed analyst can extrapolate from statistical inferences to inferences about the real world. See this discussion of the topic: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/164_2019_286

There are at least 4 possible values which would answer your question. But there is also a (very big) caveat...

Effect size (e.g. Cohen's d): in your case of a paired t-test, it is the observed means of the paired differences, divided by the observed standard deviation of the paired differences.
Confidence interval of the said Cohen's d effect size. See e.g. here for how to compute this.
Mean of the paired differences.
Confidence interval of the mean of the paired differences. See e.g. here for how to compute.

All right, now for the caveat. You write "This result would be used to support the conclusion from the p-value". This is a common misconception, but none of the above values can add support to your p-value, because all of them are direct, deterministic consequences of your p-value. If your p-value is significant, your effect size was large "enough", the mean difference was large "enough", the CI of the effect did not include 0, and the CI of the mean of the paired differences did not include 0. All are just different sides of the same coin. For example, see here on CV.
Now, the estimated mean of the differences (and its CI) is still a useful information, in as much as it tells you that the effect you demonstrated is clinically (or commercially, or academically, or however in your given context) substantial, or not: do we practically care about such an effect? Even though you statistically demonstrated a weight loss (e.g.) effect of 0.5lb, it is not clinically meaningful. And if you demonstrated a weight loss effect of 5lbs, which might be clinically meaningful, but its CI goes down to 0.2lbs, your study had too much uncertainty to be able to claim that you found a clinically meaningful effect.
Note that "effect sizes" (e.g. Cohen's d) are not that intuitive to interpret. They are unitless (ratio of the mean to the sd), and so it is not clear whether, in your particular domain, an effect of .5 is important, or trivial.
So, yes, you can report some other metrics, beyond the p-value, which may be informative for your audience, because they answer question beyond "statistical significance". But none of them will "support" your p-value.
